# Proving that two statements are equivalent

Tags: calculus

I got this question for homework, and I am not sure I fully understand it:

> Prove that the next two statements are equivalent: $$\exists
>  L\forall\epsilon\gt0\exists P:P\lt x\rightarrow\|f(x)-L\|\lt \epsilon$$
>   $$\exists L\forall\epsilon\gt0\exists P\gt0:P\lt x\rightarrow\|f(x)-L\|\lt
>  \epsilon$$

Both statements say that $f(x)$ has a limit $L$ when $x\rightarrow\infty$.
The definition of limit in infinity does not require anything from $P$, so what am I supposed to show here? Thanks

Comment: The first statement makes no sense. What does "there exists greater than..." mean??

Comment: fixed it, not its ok

Comment: It should be clear that (2)$\implies$(1). Other implication: If you know that a $P$ with such properties exists, can you see that there exists also some $P'$ which has the same properties and it is, in addition to it, positive.

Comment: Well "The definition of limit in infinity does not require anything from P, so what am I supposed to show here?" is basically the informal answer to the question.

Statement 2 clearly implies Statement 1. The other way round is harder. Let's have  athink...

Edit: I like Martin's way for (1) implies (2)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are supposed to formally prove that both statements imply each other.

Let $H(P)$ be "$P<x → ||f(x)-L||<ε$".

The second one implies the first because $∃P>0~H(P)$ implies $∃P~H(P)$.

The first one implies the second one because if you have $H(P)$ then you can find $P'$ such that $P'>0$ and $H(P')$. For example, $P'=|P|+1>0$ works.